# WPF RibbonGroup increased FontSize text cut off

Tags: wpf, xaml

In a WPF 4.5 project I'm trying to adjust the FontSize of my ribbon, but if I increase the FontSize to for example 20, the label of my RibbonGroup label is cut off and not readable:

[image: cut off text]

the code I used to create this sample is the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon>
            <RibbonTab Header="Test">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Test" FontSize="20">

                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(don't forget to include in System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon assembly)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: this may not be what you want, but try this `        <Ribbon>
            <RibbonTab Header="Test">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Test" FontSize="20" >
                    <RibbonGroup.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </RibbonGroup.HeaderTemplate>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
`

Comment: I can see the whole text now, so it's a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be what you want, but you could change the appearance of `RibbonGroup` Header by providing a `HeaderTemplate`.

This is what I tried:

```
<Ribbon>
    <RibbonTab Header="Test">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Test" FontSize="20" >
            <RibbonGroup.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </RibbonGroup.HeaderTemplate>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

and it appears to be working fine in my test app. However, you may have problems once have some more content in the `RibbonGroup`.